# How to add customized box shadow

Tags: css, box-shadow

I just want box shadow like in the design below image

[image]

And i have tried the following code for all

`box-shadow: inset 0 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.39);`

But the output was look like

[image]

I have changed the box shadow values can't get the exact ouput. Anyone help this.. Thanks.

Comment: might help: http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/.  If not please create an [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better you use the `-webkit-box-shadow`, `-moz-box-shadow`& `box-shadow` for the better output.

```css
input{
  width:100px;
  padding:15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.39);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.select-style {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background: #e5e5e5 url("http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/images/arrowdown.gif") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.select-style select {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
}

.select-style select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <option value="orders">Completed Orders</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
    <option value="class">Class</option>
  </select>
</div>
```